# Finding cosets in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find all of the cosets of $16\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and of $16\mathbb{Z}$ in $4\mathbb{Z}$.

The cosets of $16\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ would be $16\mathbb{Z}$, $1+16\mathbb{Z}$, $2+16\mathbb{Z}$, $3+16\mathbb{Z}$, $4 + 16\mathbb{Z}, \dots, 15+16\mathbb{Z}$.

The cosets of $16\mathbb{Z}$ in $4\mathbb{Z}$ would be $2 + 16\mathbb{Z}$, $4 + 16\mathbb{Z}$, $8 + 16\mathbb{Z}$, $12 + 16\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, do I have to list the right cosets too, or since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, I don't have to list them.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian (so are $16\mathbb{Z}$ and $4\mathbb{Z}$), the left and right cosets are symmetric.

Comment: $2+16\mathbb Z$ is *not* a coset of $16\mathbb Z\subset 4\mathbb Z$. Actually $(2+16\mathbb Z)\cap 4\mathbb Z=\emptyset$

Answer (score 2):

Every group of the form $n\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, and hence, abelian. In abelian groups, the left and right cosets are the same.

Note: $2 + 16\mathbb Z$ is not a coset of $16\mathbb Z $ in $4\mathbb Z$. And you've left out the coset $16 \mathbb Z$.